# Completing an incomplete GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql

MySQL allows for typically invalid SQL of performing GROUP BY with an incomplete list.  What would it try to expand to if `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` is not enabled?

Say I had this query

```sql
select
    `als_file`.`FileID`,
    `als_file`.`Date`,
    `als_file`.`Name`,
    `als_file`.`Owner`,
    `als_file`.`DisplayName`,
    `als_file`.`Description`,
    `DOWNLOADFILES`.`FilePathName`
from
    als_permission
left outer join als_file on
    `als_file`.`FileID` = `als_permission`.`File`
left outer join als_file_attribute on
    `als_file`.`FileID` = `als_file_attribute`.`file`
left outer join DOWNLOADFILES on
    `als_file`.`FileID` = `DOWNLOADFILES`.`Descrip`
where
    (`als_file`.`FileType` = ?
    and `als_file`.`Folder` = ?
    and `DOWNLOADFILES`.`Project` = ?)
group by
    `als_permission`.`File`
having 
  count(`als_permission`.`File`) <= 1
```

what would the equivalent SQL of this query be with the a complete GROUP BY

Comment: Depends on what you want to see. Your current query is problematic